# Simple question regarding Gauss's electric law

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

I just read that electric flux=enclosed charge/permittivity.

Considering the charge in an enclosed surface is always 0, what is the point in even having this equation?

Or is the equation actually electric flux= charge/ permittivity? So therefore the surface does not always have to be closed and you can have any charge, not just an enclosed charge?

This was on hyperphysics:

> *Gauss's Law: The total of the electric flux out of a closed surface is equal to the charge enclosed divided by the permittivity.*

Why not just say the flux out of a closed surface is equal to 0 instead of relating it to Q which is also 0?

Comment: Why do you think the charge in an enclosed surface is always zero? What about a sphere centered on a single electron?

Comment: well...... it is really not a physics question. No apples in my hands v.s. nothing in my hands. There is really no difference. The former is better, IF I often try to keep apples in my hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considering the charge in an enclosed surface is always 0

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this but do understand that the [Gaussian surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_surface) 'encloses' a *volume* of space within which the *enclosed charge* resides.

For example, consider an isolated point charge $q$.  Due the spherical symmetry, the appropriate Gaussian surface is a sphere of radius $r > 0$ centered on the charge.

There is no doubt that there is charge within the volume enclosed by this surface and the electric flux through the surface is simply $\Phi_E = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$ by Gauss's law.